# Makefile:434: *** mixed implicit and normal rules. Stop

Tags: command-line, fedora, make

Am using Fedora and tried to install L7-filter on linux-2.6.26 kernel.
One of the steps is to run {# make menuconfig} but am getting this error

```
Makefile:434: *** mixed implicit and normal rules.  Stop.
```

Comment: Try to figure out where in the `Makefile` the error is occurring (by looking at the last command that completes successfully before the error).  Then make a copy of the `Makefile` and start deleting things that seem to be irrelevant to the error.  If the error goes away, the last thing you deleted was probably integral to the error; put it back in and make a note of it.  When you can reproduce the error with a trimmed-down `Makefile` that is 50 lines or fewer (preferably 25 lines or fewer), [edit] your question to show the `Makefile`.  P.S. 434 is a line number — start looking there.

Comment: what fedora are you using with such old kernel? I have 4.3.4

Answer (score -1):

Chances are that the module you're compiling requires a newer version of GNU make than the distribution you have. If that's the case then you won't be able to compile that module for your kernel anyway — kernel interfaces change faster than make. 2.6.26 is ancient.

Fedora has a fast release cycle. You should have stopped running a version with kernel 2.6.26 ages ago. Reinstall your machine with an up-to-date distribution.